# How to modify Bubble sorting?

Tags: c++

{12,9,5,14,55,72,110,133} is an hard coded array .
what I want is to modify bubble sort so that it does not evaluate (or go) to the next indexing if it  is already sorted ...

I'm sorry I don't know how to explain this  but i want a algorithm which will evaluate an array without seeing it ...

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int swap(int* arr1,int* arr2);
void bubble(int arr[],int size);
void print(int size,int arr[]);

int swap(int* arr1,int* arr2){
    int temp;

    temp=*arr1;
    *arr1=*arr2;
    *arr2=temp;

}//swap

void bubble(int arr[],int size){
    for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<size-i-1;j++){
            if(arr[j]>arr[j+1]){
                swap(arr[j],arr[j+1]);
            }// if  
        }// for i
    }// for j
}//bubble



void print(int size,int arr[]){
    for(int i=0; i<size;i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<"\t";
    } // for
}// print



main(){
    int arr[8]={12,9,5,14,55,72,110,133},size=8;
    bubble(arr,size);
    print(size,arr);

}//main
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your version of the bubble sort is you will continue to compare the elements of your array even if it is sorted.

To optimize your algorithm, you may want to stop it when it is sorted. It is the case when you make no swap during one loop of your first `for` loop.

It gives this code for the `bubble` function:

```
void bubble(int arr[],int size){
    for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++){
        bool sorted = true;

        for(int j=0;j<size-i-1;j++){
            if(arr[j]>arr[j+1]){
                swap(arr[j],arr[j+1]);
                sorted = false;
            }// if  
        }// for j

        if(sorted)
            return;
    }// for i
}//bubble
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the array is sorted before calling `bubble`.

Something like:

```
bool isSorted(int* arr, size_t size) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And in main only execute `bubble` if the array is not sorted:

```
int main() {
    int arr[] = { 12,9,5,14,55,72,110,133 };
    size_t size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    if (!isSorted(arr, size)) //only if it's not sorted
        bubble(arr, size);
    print(size, arr);

}//main
```

[**Live sample here**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ORztVBIZDh86kztQ)